# squiggly trees in latex

Tags: linguistics, trees

I need to draws trees, in which one of the branches is squiggly, as showed in the screenshots below. Does anybody know how I can do that?

[image]

adapted from: Svenonius, P. (2015). Spanning. Ms., University of Tromso.

[image]

adapted from: Merchant, J. (2015). How Much Context Is Enough? Two Cases of Span-Conditioned Stem Allomorphy. Linguistic Inquiry, 46(2).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you have so far? The second diagram is not a tree at all. Any of the standard Ti*k*Z-based ways to draw a tree can do the squiggles. I assume the same is true for the `pstricks` approaches. If you really need generic graphs, you need a different approach, obviously. If you just need to add the odd edge here and there, you can draw it after the main tree using Ti*k*Z. `tikz-qtree`, `forest`, Ti*k*Z's built-in support for trees or the `trees` library. Or the graph-drawing stuff. Or ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would, naturally, use Forest because I happen to like it. It is very powerful and extremely flexible. I would load it with the `linguistics` library defaults

```
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
```

use a Ti*k*Z library for the wiggly line

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
```

and define a couple of styles for convenience.

```
\forestset{%
  /tikz/squiggly/.style={decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=.5mm, segment length=2mm}},
```

A Ti*k*Z style for wiggly lines.

```
  wiggly/.style={edge=squiggly},
```

A Forest style for wiggly edges.

```
  move me/.style n args=2{%
    before drawing tree={%
      x+=#1,
      y+=#2,
    },
  },
```

A Forest style for moving nodes to strange positions, overriding the locations calculated by the packing mechanism.

```
}
```

`no edge` can be used to block an edge and `phantom` can be used to create invisible nodes which just help with positioning.

Then the first tree can be drawn with

```
\begin{forest}
  [root
    [un, no edge]
    [dau, wiggly, no edge, move me={-5pt}{-20pt}]
    [tri, wiggly, move me={-10pt}{-40pt}]
    [pedwar, wiggly, move me={-15pt}{-60pt}]
    [, phantom, calign with current]
    [pump
      [chwech, roof]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: wiggly tree]

Substituting the actual content

```
\begin{forest}
  [D\textsubscript{[+DEF,+F,-PL]}
  [\emph{un} <D\textsubscript{[-DEF,-F,-PL]}>, no edge, move me={200pt}{0pt}]
  [\emph{une} <D\textsubscript{[-DEF,+F,-PL]}>, wiggly, no edge, move me={100pt}{-20pt}]
  [\emph{le} <D\textsubscript{[+DEF,-PL]}>, wiggly, move me={60pt}{-40pt}]
  [\emph{la} <D\textsubscript{[+DEF,+F,-PL]}>, wiggly, move me={15pt}{-60pt}]
    [, phantom, calign with current]
    [NP
      [école, roof]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: content into wiggly tree]

The second diagram is not a tree, but it is a tree except for one edge, so I'd just use `tikz` to add the extra line.

```
          [I, tikz+={\draw [squiggly] (.parent anchor) -- (!sL.child anchor); }
```

To get the final nodes aligned, I would use `tier` and, since there's a regularity here, I'd add `wiggly` for all terminal nodes and use a phantom to prevent the single exception being aligned at the bottom of the tree.

Then

```
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{
    wiggly,
    tier=terminus
  }{},
  [A
    [B
      [D
        [F
          [H
            [J
              [,phantom]
              [K]
            ]
          ]
          [I, tikz+={\draw [squiggly] (.parent anchor) -- (!sL.child anchor); }
            [,phantom]
          ]
        ]
        [G
          [L]
        ]
      ]
      [E
        [M]
      ]
    ]
    [C
      [N]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

will produce the second non-tree.

[image: wiggly non-tree]

Shamelessly plugging [Alan Munn's content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326386/) into the second structure above,

```
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{
    wiggly,
    tier=terminus
  }{},
  [T
    [Asp
      [Voice
        [$v$
          [V
            [$\sqrt{\text{EAT}}$
              [,phantom]
              [fayo]
            ]
          ]
          [$v$, tikz+={\draw [squiggly] (.parent anchor) -- (!sL.child anchor); }
            [,phantom]
          ]
        ]
        [Voice\\\textminus act
          [o]
        ]
      ]
      [Aspect\\+perf
        [ik]
      ]
    ]
    [{T\\+past,1sg}
      [a]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: shameless wiggly non-tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\forestset{%
  /tikz/squiggly/.style={decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=.5mm, segment length=2mm}},
  wiggly/.style={edge=squiggly},
  move me/.style n args=2{%
    before drawing tree={%
      x+=#1,
      y+=#2,
    },
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  [root
    [un, no edge]
    [dau, wiggly, no edge, move me={-5pt}{-20pt}]
    [tri, wiggly, move me={-10pt}{-40pt}]
    [pedwar, wiggly, move me={-15pt}{-60pt}]
    [, phantom, calign with current]
    [pump
      [chwech, roof]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [D\textsubscript{[+DEF,+F,-PL]}
  [\emph{un} <D\textsubscript{[-DEF,-F,-PL]}>, no edge, move me={200pt}{0pt}]
  [\emph{une} <D\textsubscript{[-DEF,+F,-PL]}>, wiggly, no edge, move me={100pt}{-20pt}]
  [\emph{le} <D\textsubscript{[+DEF,-PL]}>, wiggly, move me={60pt}{-40pt}]
  [\emph{la} <D\textsubscript{[+DEF,+F,-PL]}>, wiggly, move me={15pt}{-60pt}]
    [, phantom, calign with current]
    [NP
      [école, roof]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{
    wiggly,
    tier=terminus
  }{},
  [A
    [B
      [D
        [F
          [H
            [J
              [,phantom]
              [K]
            ]
          ]
          [I, tikz+={\draw [squiggly] (.parent anchor) -- (!sL.child anchor); }
            [,phantom]
          ]
        ]
        [G
          [L]
        ]
      ]
      [E
        [M]
      ]
    ]
    [C
      [N]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}    
\begin{forest}
  where n children=0{
    wiggly,
    tier=terminus
  }{align=center},
  [T
    [Asp
      [Voice
        [$v$
          [V
            [$\sqrt{\text{EAT}}$
              [,phantom]
              [fayo]
            ]
          ]
          [$v$, tikz+={\draw [squiggly] (.parent anchor) -- (!sL.child anchor); }
            [,phantom]
          ]
        ]
        [Voice\\\textminus act
          [o]
        ]
      ]
      [Aspect\\+perf
        [ik]
      ]
    ]
    [{T\\+past,1sg}
      [a]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `align=center` is standard with the `linguistics` library loaded.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks. Corrected, I think. I'd either forgotten or never knew that. If you want me to delete the tree using your stolen content, let me know. I would completely understand.

Comment: No, that's fine. :) I actually like adding `\phantom{x}` nodes instead of just using `phantom` as it spaces out the multidominance lines a bit better. Your `move-me` code is very cool.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I noticed you did that, but I wasn't sure why. I'm not sure what multidominance lines are. (Cases where the child has more than one parent?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. For various types of linguistic analysis they are becoming more popular. They're horrible to draw however, in the general case.

Comment: Thank you, @cfr! To clarify, I didn't mean to ask you to do it for me - I was actually wondering about the correct package to do that.

Comment: @RobertP. Fair enough. Usually when people post an image without code, they do seem to expect answers which just give them the code for the image. Note that even providing a document with just the content of the nodes makes it easier to help - especially if the content is from a discipline you're not familiar with. (That's why I stole Alan Munn's - he's a linguist. For me, the content has little meaning.)

Comment: @cfr: I was wondering how the coordinates of `move me` work. Can you clarify that to me? I have been trying to figure that out on my own, but I need some help.

Comment: @RobertP. They are just adjustments to the `x` and `y` coordinates which the node would normally have. The node just gets shifted horizontally and vertically by the given amounts.

Comment: so, I don't know why but my tree is too large and I can't figure out how to adjust it. How can I show what I mean?

Comment: @RobertP. You could edit your question, but it would probably be better to ask a follow-up question (i.e. a new question with a link to this one) or to ask in chat. [Assuming I've understood correctly that you're not having trouble with the original trees in this question but another tree.]

Answer (score 7):

The first tree is barely a tree, and so you may want to draw it manually with a matrix of nodes.  The second tree is fairly straightforward but needs some trickery to have the multidominance structure for the *v* structure since (as cfr correctly notes), multidominance 'trees' are not strictly speaking, trees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\tikzset{decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} where n children=0{tier=word, edge=decorate}{}
[T [Asp [Voice 
      [v [V\\$\sqrt{\text{\scshape eat}}$,name=V [\phantom{v},no edge]]
      [faɣo,no edge, name=Vroot] 
      [v,name=v [\phantom{v},no edge]]][Voice\\$-$act [θ]]]
   [Aspect\\$+$perf [ik]]] 
   [T\\{$+$past,1sg} [a]]]
\draw[decorate] (v.south) -- (Vroot.north);
\draw[decorate] (V.south) -- (Vroot.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I don't understand why I didn't see your answer when I looked at this question, given that you posted it half an hour before mine. (I wouldn't have answered it if I'd known you'd already done so.)

Comment: @cfr No idea. And you solved the first part in a very clever way, so there's no real problem.

Comment: Thanks. I like the `\phantom{v}` spacing. ... A bit of Welsh ;)

Comment: Also, I don't know why my answer has a vote more than yours. That doesn't seem fair. I'd vote for yours again if the system would let me - justice should be done!

Comment: @cfr Well yours does the first "tree", and mine doesn't. And yours doesn't have any extra `\draw` commands for the multidominance. And yours is just bigger! :)

Comment: @cfr, if it makes you feel any better, I'll vote for Alan's and not yours, even though I think they both deserve upvotes!

Comment: @JasonZentz Now Alan's is listed first, it should get more votes anyway. (Plus the points for acceptance, of course.)